Why weren't comments moved to chat?
I accepted the "move to chat" suggestion, the chat was created, but the comments are still on the answer and it is still suggesting that I move them to chat:

How should one actually move comments?

Did you flag them to be deleted. That announcement is an automated suggestion only. Please simply ask the moderators to delete comments.

@KenGraham, I've flagged them by hand now. So is this a bug that the "automatically move" question doesn't actually automatically move them?

Even the mods have to specifically tick a box to delete the comments when moving to chat. It makes sense that regular users aren't able to delete other people's comments.

@curiousdannii, In that case, it should say "copy", not "move", to avoid confusion. And the term "automatically" makes it even worse.

I read it as saying moving the discussion to chat, not previous comments. The intent is that any further discussion will continue in chat. Of course it can't stop being continuing to comment...

@curiousdannii says "moving the discussion to chat, not previous comments". But it did put the comments into the chat. If the purpose of "move to chat" is to get rid of them from the answer, what's the point of leaving them all there in the original location?

"If the purpose of "move to chat" is to get rid of them from the answer," That's not the primary purpose. The purpose is to shift where the discussion is happening. Nothing can change where the discussion was happening, only where it will continue. As a mod I'll typically have to evaluate each comment to decide whether it's value feedback that should remain, or part of a discussion that has been moved to chat.

I believe this is a better question for Philosophy.SE, but I'll try here:

christianity.stackexchange.com is not a discussion forum
there could be no discussion on the website
Moving, in computer parlance, means cutting and pasting
therefore the discussion is present only in the minds of the discussers
therefore moving the discussion to chat is the correct term insofar as it cuts the discussion (which only existed in the minds of the discussers) and pastes it in chat, where the minds are free to roam - so long as they refrain from vulgarity.


But it wasn't "cutting and pasting" (moving), it was "copying and pasting" (duplicating). There's a very significant difference, and that's what confused me.

@ray it was cutting and pasting the metaphysical discussion while leaving the accidents on the main site
